# Is it possible to backup all the files under chrome/developer tools/sources?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-developer-tools

I loaded a site and checking developer tools I can see a lot of folders and files under the Sources section, aunder a folder called top.

Is there a way or extension to help me copy all those folders and files to my hard drive?

Even if it's a third party tool would help, at the moment I cannot think on anything else other than manually copying everything, which would take quite a while!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into DevTools, but you may be able to run a [snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/snippets) that downloads all the page's resources. I'm not sure what that code would look like. The basic idea would be to open the page, and then run the snippet on the page, with the code somehow iterating through and downloading every requested resource.

Could also be worth looking into Chrome Extensions that handle this. They have access to the Chrome Debugging Protocol which may give them deeper access to the page's resources.

Comment: Thank you Kayce, I didn't manage to find anything, but I was not sure if I was researching correctly.

If I find something useful, I'll update it here for future reference...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is currently possible by going into the Network tab and right clicking any request and clicking "Download All as HAR"

Comment: I don't know if a HAR file is doing the same? ie, if I go to the 'Sources' tab, I can see a lot of folders and individual files (.js, scripts, css, images, etc). 

Can I access all those individual files and see their syntax on my local drive if all I've got is a HAR file instead?

Comment: @mickael The HAR file contains every resource (INCLUDING CONTENTS) put together into a JSON file. You can use a script to process it